# Can Windows OS be installed read-only?

Tags: security, read-only

Can Windows OS be installed and then made read-only so that malware can be cleared by a reboot?  If so, how?

Can Windows be installed to a VM, then make all the underlying VM files read-only and still have Windows boot OK?

I used to have a CD with an old version Windows on it, and that did the trick (lost the CD ages ago).  I have a CentOS build from the DoD that works, but I'm not a Unix guy.

Comment: You can use something like [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/enterprise/). With a simple reboot, any unwelcome or unwanted changes are removed from the system, restoring it to the original state.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Enhanced Write Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838511%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx).

Many [thin clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) which run Windows OS use this technology to protect system drive.

Main concept is that all changes to protected hard drive are actually going to special area (RAM or special partition on the hard drive). All changes take effect - you can change settings and write to the disk. But after reboot all those changes will be lost.

In case if you need to make permanent changes you can `commit changes` to the protected volume.

You will need to replace some of the system files, which can be **dangerous**.

You can Google for additional info by searching for `Enhanced Write Filter`.

Here is another [link](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?52577-E-W-F-Embedded-Enhanced-Write-Filter-locking-down-the-OS-partition-to-enhance-drive-working-life)

And [one more](http://www.mp3car.com/winnt-based/140081-ewf-on-windows-7-32-bit-or-64-bit-enhanced-write-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

Windows can be installed to a VM - but you will need a valid license to do so.

The simplest solution would be to create a VM with Windows installed and then back that up.

Then whenever you want to run Windows restore the backup, fire up the VM and Windows and off you go. The VM can't accesses any hardware without your express permission and so the rest of the system will be safe. Then when you're done simply delete the VM.